# How to automate WordPress Movie website for different Movie's Poster, Trailer, Info, Screenshots and download link to reduce involvement in process?

Tags: wordpress, automation, rss, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I have a movie website on WordPress where I post movies with their respective Poster, Trailer, About movie, Story line, some Screenshot and download link. this is very tedious task to post every movie by manually changing and replacing the new content every time for different post. i want to automate this process or reduce my involvement in the process and make most of the work by automation. How to do that? Is there any stack of plugins? Could you please provide guidance. Ask me if anything is unclear.

I've watched many video tutorial but none of them able to solve it and i don't understand how to do that.

Comment: You can use any movie API for your needs such as TMDB OMDB or IMDB itself. https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/intro/getting-started

Comment: thank you snuffy, could you tell me and give me any reference, how to use these api in wordpress?

Comment: I started a movie distributed website. how can I make the automatic post for new release movies using these apis.

Comment: This is not a tutorial website how to. There is tones of info about API's out there. Any tutorial about any API would do. The principle is the same. Just the data will be different.